# Resetting all provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Coming back to my account after some time all of my provisioning profiles have expired. Since they were often duplicated, I would like to make a clean start. Should I simply try to delete all profiles and start again? Is this the correct way forward?

Comment: Sure, that works. You may need to renew your certificates first if they have expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. Blow away all Prov Profiles out of Organizer
2. Revoke every Cert in the Dev Portal
3. Delete all Prov Profiles from the Portal
4. Start the CSR process all over again

I would NOT

1. Remove any devices from the portal since they still count against you
2. If you have an Enterprise account delete the Distribution Cert of any active apps

Comment: What if one does not have a paid certified developer account?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to start form scratch, I recommend you delete your profiles, possibly renew your certificates, and make new profiles as you need them.